# Dynamically populating column in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to translate a function I use to calculate skew over each feature of a dataframe.
I calculate 2 skews, one for the feature when `date == d`, and one over the data when `date <= d`.
I was able to translate the first line of the following code but not the second.
The code to recreate a dataframe :

```
import random
date = [random.choice([1,2,3]) for x in range(0,100)]
feature1 = [random.gauss(0,1) for x in range(0,100)]
feature2 = [random.gauss(0,2) for x in range(0,100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":date,'feature1':feature1,'feature2':feature2})
```

Here is the pandas function:

```
def features_augment(df):
    dff = df.copy()
    for col,d in itertools.product(dff.columns[2:],dff.date.unique()):
        dff.loc[dff.date==d,'sk_'+col] = scipy.stats.skew(dff.loc[dff.date==d,col]) #translated in polars
        dff.loc[dff.date==d,'rsk_'+col] = scipy.stats.skew(dff.loc[dff.date<=d,col]) #couldn't translate
    return dff
```

Here is my polars function so far:

```
def pl_feature_augment(df):
    pl_df = pl.from_pandas(df)
    sk = pl_df.groupby("date").agg(pl.all().exclude("id","volvol").skew().prefix("sk_")) #calculate skew on for each feature on each date 
    pl_df = pl_df.join(sk,"date")
    for d in pl_df.select(pl.col("date")).unique():
        pl_df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("date")<=d).then(pl.all().exclude("id","vol","volvol").skew()).prefix("rsk_")) #doesn't work 

return pl_df.to_pandas()
```

I managed to avoid the `for` loop for the first expression but can't figure out how to translate the second one even with a `for` loop...

Comment: Which `product` function is that you're using? In the first example with the pandas function definition. Also a minimal working example of the data you're using (code establishing the dataframe in pandas) would be helpful

Comment: I edited the question with the requested changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extra feature column for example purposes:

```
pl_df = pl.from_repr("""
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ date ┆ feature1  ┆ feature2  ┆ feature3  │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64  ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 3    ┆ -0.71728  ┆ 0.149132  ┆ 1.001409  │
│ 1    ┆ 1.303821  ┆ -1.621259 ┆ -0.261638 │
│ 1    ┆ -0.180873 ┆ -0.777132 ┆ 0.967881  │
│ 1    ┆ -0.438287 ┆ 0.304117  ┆ 0.736307  │
│ 2    ┆ -0.489215 ┆ -1.239215 ┆ 2.767833  │
│ 3    ┆ 0.209194  ┆ -1.106649 ┆ -0.73973  │
│ 1    ┆ 0.516778  ┆ 0.26425   ┆ 2.80841   │
│ 1    ┆ 0.482522  ┆ 1.146356  ┆ -0.752033 │
│ 3    ┆ -0.760755 ┆ 0.211106  ┆ 0.00278   │
│ 2    ┆ 0.665081  ┆ -1.140646 ┆ 3.009091  │
│ 3    ┆ 0.027294  ┆ 1.385364  ┆ 1.848935  │
│ 1    ┆ -0.109353 ┆ 2.698282  ┆ -1.080152 │
│ 3    ┆ -0.50849  ┆ -3.916603 ┆ -4.422061 │
│ 1    ┆ -1.273324 ┆ -0.0369   ┆ -3.589582 │
│ 2    ┆ -0.926717 ┆ -2.338863 ┆ 1.815631  │
│ 1    ┆ -0.906546 ┆ 1.224383  ┆ 0.145775  │
│ 3    ┆ -0.459142 ┆ 1.01782   ┆ -1.900232 │
│ 1    ┆ 0.371648  ┆ 3.509538  ┆ -0.654882 │
│ 2    ┆ 0.958224  ┆ -2.368278 ┆ 0.618381  │
│ 1    ┆ -0.235959 ┆ 1.326076  ┆ 5.704977  │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
""")
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this in a single pass using existing groupby/join methods.

(It seems like it can be expressed as a non-equi join which are on the TODO list.)

We can build a sequence of LazyFrames which allows Polars to run the computations in parallel:

```
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(df).lazy()

dates = pl_df.select("date").unique().collect().iter_rows()

skews = (
   pl_df.filter(pl.col("date") <= date)
        .select(
           pl.lit(date, int).alias("date"),
           pl.exclude("date", "id", "volvol").skew().prefix("rsk_")
        )
   for date in dates
)

(pl_df
   .with_columns(
      pl.exclude("date", "id", "volvol").skew().over("date").prefix("sk_")
   )
   .join(
      pl.concat(skews), 
      on = "date", 
      how = "left"
   )
   .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (20, 10)
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ date ┆ feature1  ┆ feature2  ┆ feature3  ┆ sk_feature1 ┆ sk_feature2 ┆ sk_feature3 ┆ rsk_feature1 ┆ rsk_feature2 ┆ rsk_feature3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ i64  ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64         ┆ f64         ┆ f64         ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 3    ┆ -0.71728  ┆ 0.149132  ┆ 1.001409  ┆ 0.511999    ┆ -1.094016   ┆ -0.607669   ┆ 0.366071     ┆ -0.106414    ┆ 0.019972     │
│ 1    ┆ 1.303821  ┆ -1.621259 ┆ -0.261638 ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 1    ┆ -0.180873 ┆ -0.777132 ┆ 0.967881  ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 1    ┆ -0.438287 ┆ 0.304117  ┆ 0.736307  ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 2    ┆ -0.489215 ┆ -1.239215 ┆ 2.767833  ┆ -0.062774   ┆ 0.009747    ┆ -0.517757   ┆ 0.052201     ┆ 0.364357     ┆ 0.214142     │
│ 3    ┆ 0.209194  ┆ -1.106649 ┆ -0.73973  ┆ 0.511999    ┆ -1.094016   ┆ -0.607669   ┆ 0.366071     ┆ -0.106414    ┆ 0.019972     │
│ 1    ┆ 0.516778  ┆ 0.26425   ┆ 2.80841   ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 1    ┆ 0.482522  ┆ 1.146356  ┆ -0.752033 ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 3    ┆ -0.760755 ┆ 0.211106  ┆ 0.00278   ┆ 0.511999    ┆ -1.094016   ┆ -0.607669   ┆ 0.366071     ┆ -0.106414    ┆ 0.019972     │
│ 2    ┆ 0.665081  ┆ -1.140646 ┆ 3.009091  ┆ -0.062774   ┆ 0.009747    ┆ -0.517757   ┆ 0.052201     ┆ 0.364357     ┆ 0.214142     │
│ 3    ┆ 0.027294  ┆ 1.385364  ┆ 1.848935  ┆ 0.511999    ┆ -1.094016   ┆ -0.607669   ┆ 0.366071     ┆ -0.106414    ┆ 0.019972     │
│ 1    ┆ -0.109353 ┆ 2.698282  ┆ -1.080152 ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 3    ┆ -0.50849  ┆ -3.916603 ┆ -4.422061 ┆ 0.511999    ┆ -1.094016   ┆ -0.607669   ┆ 0.366071     ┆ -0.106414    ┆ 0.019972     │
│ 1    ┆ -1.273324 ┆ -0.0369   ┆ -3.589582 ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 2    ┆ -0.926717 ┆ -2.338863 ┆ 1.815631  ┆ -0.062774   ┆ 0.009747    ┆ -0.517757   ┆ 0.052201     ┆ 0.364357     ┆ 0.214142     │
│ 1    ┆ -0.906546 ┆ 1.224383  ┆ 0.145775  ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 3    ┆ -0.459142 ┆ 1.01782   ┆ -1.900232 ┆ 0.511999    ┆ -1.094016   ┆ -0.607669   ┆ 0.366071     ┆ -0.106414    ┆ 0.019972     │
│ 1    ┆ 0.371648  ┆ 3.509538  ┆ -0.654882 ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
│ 2    ┆ 0.958224  ┆ -2.368278 ┆ 0.618381  ┆ -0.062774   ┆ 0.009747    ┆ -0.517757   ┆ 0.052201     ┆ 0.364357     ┆ 0.214142     │
│ 1    ┆ -0.235959 ┆ 1.326076  ┆ 5.704977  ┆ 0.088205    ┆ 0.25369     ┆ 0.715095    ┆ 0.088205     ┆ 0.25369      ┆ 0.715095     │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

As we're using the Lazy API here, `pl.concat(skews)` is parallelized.

Comment: to make sure I understood your code, you applied it only to feature 2? So the loop should be extended with itertools.product too in order to cover all the features but I am wondering if the performance in that case would be better than the one in pandas

Comment: Ah right, I see now, with more `feature` columns the behaviour differs due to the `.product` - will update.

Comment: Cheers, yeah the code runs in pandas on about 500 features in approx 10-12min

Comment: Should the code not use `d` in the column name? `dff.loc[dff.date==d,'rsk_'+col]` <- `"rsk_" + col` is only producing a single `feature2` output column as it's being overwritten in each loop iteration.

Comment: yeah as far as I could go, I had a for loop for the days `d` and using pl.all() allowed to process in parallel, BUT each day the column is rewritten, loosing the previous computations. I tried to sort asc or desc, detect when values is none etc ... the isssue is always with the `date<=d`

Comment: I see, well perhaps you could add `feature3` to your example and show the output you want to generate. I've modified the approach to create a column for each feature/date pair which is what it sounds like you're after?

Comment: yeah that's idea but you have null here because the column is recalculated each time, instead of being modified in place... I will edit the post tmr to explain precisely what i want and what I achieved so far

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. The pandas version is modifying only a subset of rows in-place per iteration resulting in a single `rsk_featureN` column. It was difficult for me to parse that for whatever reason. I've updated the code to do that and added in the `sk_` too.